# Spacing betwen centered text and prose

Tags: spacing, titles, line-spacing

I have some left-aligned text followed by some centered text followed by a section of left-aligned prose.  How do I make the space between the line of left-aligned text and the centered text (and then the centered text and the long section of prose) equal to the spacing between lines of a double-spaced paragraph?

Here's what I have now in TeXworks.  The space above and below the centered text is not equal to the space between lines of double-spaced prose, but I would like it to be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Name \thepage}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is My Name\\
This is Another Part\\
This is Another Part\\
This is the Date
\pagebreak[0]
\begin{center}
Title of Work
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in,headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Name \thepage}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is My Name\\
This is Another Part\\
This is Another Part\\
This is the Date
\pagebreak[0]

\begingroup
\centering
Title of Work\par       %% \par needed here very badly
\endgroup

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.

\end{document}
```

[image]